# How to allow the first digit in EditText to be a zero (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have an EditText for the user to input phone number, which is later saved to sharedpreferences. But EditText seems to remove the first digit if it is a 0, which I don't want. How do I allow the first number to be 0? I have tried using android:digits="0123456789", android:inputType="phone" and android:inputType="number". XML:

```
       <EditText
    android:id="@+id/etAnnonsNr"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="25sp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/etAnnonsText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etAnnonsText"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/boxboarder"
    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/etAnnonsPris"
    android:hint="Ditt telefonnummer"
    android:inputType="number" />
```

Java:

`final EditText etAnnonsNr = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etAnnonsNr);`

```
if (etAnnonsNr.getText().toString().matches("")){
                editor.putInt("AnnonsNr", 0);
            }else{
                editor.putInt("AnnonsNr", Integer.parseInt(etAnnonsNr.getText().toString()));
            }
editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I didn't get the question completely, but if you are using Integer anywhere, using `Strings` instead of `Integer`. Also use `editor.putString`instead of `editor.putInt`. Convert the value back from String to Integer when you want to use the value saved in `SharedPreference` as Integer. It might help retain the `0`.

Comment: The problem is, that I've defined the EditText with android:inputType="number", because the user only should be able to input numbers. Let's say I put in number 0123 in the EditText. The first event for this EditText in the javafile is: `EditText etAnnonsNr = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etAnnonsNr);` If I, directly after this put in system.out.println(etAnnonsNr), the result is 123, and the 0 is already removed. -So it wouldn't help if I change it to a string in the java- file, since the zero is already gone...

Comment: I feel stupid now.. -I've been troubleshooting the wrong activity! -Your solution works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Change your `android:inputType="number"` to `android:inputType="phone"`. Do not parse to `Integer`.

Answer (score 1):

store your no as string ie `putString` instead of `putInt` and while retreving the number just parse the string to int .Thats it

Comment: I feel stupid now.. I thought the problem was before putInt in the javafile, but itt seems I've been troubleshooting the wrong activity! -Your solution works. Thank you!